# An invalid floating point operation occurred when search long and latitude

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, precision

I use this procedure in SQL to find the near locations on Bing map by Latitude and Longitude.

The procedure returns

> An invalid floating point operation occurred

when I search by this @latitude = 7025045 , @longitude = 702342

Here is my procedure:

```
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UppdragNearByUppdrag3]
    @latitude int, 
@longitude int

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT  ARUppdrag.cUppdrNr AS UppdrNr, a.iLarmNorthing AS   LarmKoordinatNorthing, a.iLarmEasting AS LarmKoordinatEasting
FROM     Trakt AS a INNER JOIN
          ARUppdrag ON a.iTraktID = ARUppdrag.iTraktID 

WHERE a.iLarmNorthing <> 0  and a.iLarmEasting <> 0 And   (ACOS(SIN(a.iLarmNorthing * 0.0175) * SIN(@latitude * 0.0175) + COS(a.iLarmNorthing * 0.0175) * COS(@latitude * 0.0175) *
COS(@longitude * 0.0175 - a.iLarmEasting * 0.0175)) * 3959 <= 100)


END
```

Comment: Which dbms? (The code is far from ANSI SQL...)

Comment: @GordonLinoff it was just a comma,  its fixed now and its complete now that i can run other coordinates

Comment: @B.j . . . Does this problem occur with other values?

Comment: no, just whith these values.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the @longitude and @latitude to float or decimal with a large precision.  Because they are INT, when they appear as the first variable in a mathematical statement, there is an implicit type cast to INT, and then there is an invalid float point operation.

Comment: What is the datatype of a.iLarmNorthing ?  Can you add the table declaration and some data.

Comment: these two are int datatype, I have changed the procedure to float(8) and it worked for som and failed with these data latitude 7145225 longitude 766825